# Which one is faster

Tags: jquery

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div id="content">   
  <input id="txt_content"/>
  <span id="username">Niko</span>
  <span id="timestamp">some timestamp</span>
 </div>
```

**Jquery**

Approach 1

```
  $("#content").click(function(){
     var this_content = $(this); 
     var txt_content = this_content.find("#txt_content").val();
     var user_name   = this_content.find("#username").html();
     var time_stamp = this_content.find("#timestamp").html();
  });
```

Approach 2

```
 $("#content").click(function(){
     var txt_content = $("#txt_content").val(); 
     var user_name   = $("#username").html();
     var time_stamp = $("#timestamp").html();
  });
```

Could anyone kindly tell me which one is faster? and also consider if the html page contains more number of id's. I have just shown a part of it.

Yes, the 2nd approach makes use of native `document.getElementById()` which is the super fast method but I guess in the 1st approach we have already `searched` the `content` element on the `click` event and we have stored it in a `var`, Now searching of elements is limited to a small area.

I was thinking to use `find()` and get the values but some websites told me not to use any other tags or classes or id's like `(#id #content)`, just use simply `$("#content")` but the situation is different in the above case we have got a `var`

Please let me understand which one is better and faster

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark it?

Comment: you don't have to search through elements to find an element by id due to the fact that there is only one. It is directly accessible by it's id very quickly. However, when you attempt to find said element within a collection by it's id, it's far slower because now it can't use the fast way of referencing by id and instead uses the css selector engine (which is still pretty fast, just not as fast as going directly to it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use approach 2 unless you have a good reason not to. It's cleaner code — easier to read and maintain — and it's how jQuery does examples in the documentation. Any performance difference will be so extremely negligible unless you are doing it hundreds or thousands of times, in which case I would say you should refactor your code or use a different library.